# CSS background override of Bootstrap button breaks hover behavior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I have a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnve17se/) that illustrates the problem. I'm using the bootstrap CDN on my site. I've overridden the Bootstrap btn-primary class in CSS in order to make them match my site theme.

The problem: btn-primary has a hover that toggles the icon background color to a shade of blue. But when I click on the button, it seems to 'lock' onto the hover color. It will only change back if I click on the page OUTSIDE of the button.

I know I could just add !important to the background line in my CSS, but then I lose the mouseover/hover color change, which I'd like to preserve.

Can anyone explain why this is happening or give me a fix to allow my overridden button to switch back to its desired/initial color after clicking it and mousing off of it? Thanks.

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dnve17se/)

Instructions to repro problem from jsFiddle:
See the issue:

```
1. mouse over the button without clicking. Color changes for mouse on, changes back on mouse off.
2. Mouse over button
3. Click button.
4. Mouse off button.
5. Notice color of button remains the mouseover color, even if you mouse on/off button repeatedly.
6. click page outside of button.
7. notice button now changes back and mouseover behavior is restored.
```

Looking for a way to retain default mouseover behavior yet override the default bg color of the bootstrap btn-primary.

Comment: This is because bootstrap adds not only :hover but :focus - and when you click on a button, it's in focus. You can either write your own CSS hover and focus overrides or try a blur with javascript, but if you use a button to open a bootstrap widget (like a modal) closing that widget refocuses on the button again. The bad part of removing the visual cue of :focus is accessibility / keyboard tabbing.

Comment: TerraElise is correct. all you have to do is add change the rule of your `.btn-primary` to `.btn-primary, .btn-primary:focus` and your problem is solved. Here's an updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dnve17se/1/